# Solving equation with a derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following equation needs to be solved for f(x):

$1+x=\frac{\delta f(x)^2}{\delta x}$

I would take integrals at both sides, right? I am unsure about the intervals of the integals, my x has the range [o,1] so is it like this then:

$\int_0^11+x=\int_0^1\frac{\delta f(x)^2}{\delta x}$

which would result in 
$\frac{3}{2}=f(1)^2-f(0)^2$ ?
Is this thinking correct or am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Not sure what the square affects to. By other side, the rang of validity for $x$ doesn't represent the integral limits.

Comment: Is the RHS $(y^2)'(x)$ or $(y'(x))^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean : $1+x=\frac{d f(x)^2}{d x}$. 
Using the chain rule : $\implies 2f(x)f'(x)=x+1$

But it's easier to regard $g(x)=f(x)^2$ as a separate function : $f(x)^2 = x+ \frac{1}{2}x^2 + c \implies f(x)=\pm \sqrt{ x+ \frac{1}{2}x^2 + c }$

Comment: I submitted my answer and I saw your coming. So, I delete mine which was strictly identical to your. And $\to +1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It was just a few seconds.. But thanks!

Comment: I would do the same but giving an expression of $C$ in terms of $f$. I mean imposing $f(a) = \pm\sqrt{a + a^2/2 + C}$, so that $C = f(a)^2 - a - a^2/2$ where $a\in [0,1]$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! So if I take your first approach, where you took the derivative of $f(x)^2$, how can I solve the resulting equation for f(x)? (this is my task) Wouldn't I need to integrate both sides? Oh and I don't know whether that makes a differnece but it is actually $(f(x))^2$

Comment: What is wrong with integrating both sides on the interval [0,1]? the left side (1+x) integrated would be 3/2 and the right side (the one with the derivative) could be f(1)-f(0)?

Comment: Oh, and another thing I forgot to mention is that the function f(x) is strictily increasing. Am I allowed to disregard the square in $f(x)^2$ and maybe just treat it as $f(x)$?